# Job Falis SSIS Catelogue

Tags: ssis

The Job In the SSIS catalogue calls the package. When I started running job , job fails however when I go to look at all executions in the ssis catalogue , it shows status "Completed" and there is no any error message .
Any Help?

Comment: Jobs don't exist in the SSIS catalog, they exist in SQL Agent. If the job fails then the logical thing to do is of course _check the job log_. What do you find in there?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, you are right.  I clikcked view job history. it shows failure and i checked message saying "Please go to package" to see message. When i check "All execution" on the pacakge, the status is "Complete" and there is no error message showing. Any idea ?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thank you for your reply

Comment: And your certain that the execution id in the package log matches the execution id in the sql agent? You might looking at a different execution

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thank you for your help.. I just recreated new package which performs the same function. Job run successfully.